# GET request that receives a binary wav audio file

Tags: get, base64, twilio, wav, twilio-api

I am trying to make a Twilio GET request to retrieve a wav file from the following url: https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/accntsid/Recordings/pathsid.wav

My current code is:

```
public string Get(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {

            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

However, this returns `"RIFF??"` where the `"?"` represent some weird special character. So I am clearly not reading the stream correctly. According to the API documentation, with a `".wav"` extension, a binary WAV audio file is returned with mime-type `"audio/x-wav"`. Do I need to setup a byte array? The aim is to convert this .wav into a base64 string.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you shouldn't use a `StreamReader` for binary data, you will need to handle it as a `byte` array, i.e.:

```
public byte[] Get(string url)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

For this case `HttpWebRequest` isn't necessary though and you can just use `WebClient.DownloadData` to avoid all the `stream` handling, i.e.

```
public byte[] Get(string url)
{        
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        return client.DownloadData(url);
    }
}
```

Just read your last sentence - if you want base64, you can call `Convert.ToBase64String` on the `byte` array

```
public string Get(string url)
{        
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(client.DownloadData(url));
    }
}
```